# Неизвестные ошибки в процессе выполнения. Что не так?

Tags: java, android, google-api

Выполняю подключение к своему приложению через Google Sign-In.

**Вот код :**

```
package com.tlalim.masa.parksclient.activities.user;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.tlalim.masa.parksclient.R;
import com.tlalim.masa.parksclient.activities.MainMenu;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;

public class CreateAccount extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private SignInButton signInButton;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(
            googleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        signIn();
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        //Calling a new function to handle signin
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //If the login succeed
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

    } else {
        //If login fails
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

**Тут несколько вопросов :**
я пытался найти решение, но ошибки остаются
1) В логе показывает такие ошибки

```
I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

Кто нибудь может объяснить, что эти статусы означают?

2) Когда запускаю приложение открывается, и говорит что нужно получить google play services, я нажимаю кнопку получить и запускается ProgressDialog(), и после того как возвращается ответ я так понимаю он должен выключиться, но он не выключается.

Что я делаю не так? как решить хотя бы какую нибудь из ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить `.addApi` на `.addApiIfAvailable`

Comment: нет это не решило никакую из проблем(